# Solr 4.5: When is Solr facet query better than simple query?

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I'm working with Apache Solr and would like to get more detailed information about some query options. I discovered facet queries and was wondering, when exactly do they bring essential advantages; especially in case of the following example:

There is a stock of books that is saved on a Solr server. Despite the common attributes a book ought to have, they have an ISBN. Data about books is provided by third parties and so it's important to check that there are no doubled ISBNs within the system. In order to check if a book's ISBN is a duplicate, it has to go through a routed path, were - unfortunately - every book is processed indiviually without any information about preceeding or following processes.

The question is:
a) Should you simply query Solr with the current book ISBN and check the total results, or
b) should you send a facet query with a `f.isbn.facet.mincount=2` and check if the result contains the current book ISBN?

In both cases, caching results is not possible. So the number of queries would always equal the number of books processed. I simply don't know how Solr works within and therefore can't make this decision without further information, especially because the number of queries won't be reduced by either of above possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to do a query - do a query. Lucene is highly optimized for doing queries, so that's what you should do. A facet query is for creating facets (counts) from arbitrary queries - so internally it does the same thing. If you generate a facet and then iterate through that one, Lucene has to look at far more documents than if you're just querying for one single value.

The best strategy to get a performance boost would be to perform these operations in batch - check 500 books in the same batch (i.e. `isbn:(123 OR 321 OR 567 OR 765)`), and then handle that in your code. If these updates can arrive from many systems in parallel without going through one single source, you'll have to decide how much time you can spend before any duplicates might appear in the streams (this race condition can happen with just one book as well, as two streams can query for a single isbn and get a negative result before adding it separately from both streams).